# Calling your app from a calendar entry in Android

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I am writing an App, which will create calendar entries with reminders, that is no problem. On the calendar entry, I would like to add a link or reference to my App, so it can open my App passing the ID which the calendar entry is associated to. This is in a similar way Facebook calendar entries have a "Wall post" link, once clicked, will Facebook for the corresponding friend. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any success with that? I'd like something like that for my app too. It has basic reminder functionality but users require more and more features so it would actually make more sense to use the calendar app for that.